# why is this snippet valid with an explicit value, but invalid as a function?

Tags: haskell, integer

I'm trying to work a problem where I need to calculate the "small" divisors of an integer. I'm just bruteforcing through all numbers up to the square root of the given number, so to get the divisors of 10 I'd write:

```
[k|k<-[1...floor(sqrt 10)],rem 10 k<1]
```

This seems to work well. But as soon as I plug this in a function

```
f n=[k|k<-[1...floor(sqrt n)],rem n k<1]
```

And actually *call* this function, I do get an error

```
f 10

No instance for (Floating t0) arising from a use of `it'
The type variable `t0' is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Floating Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
  instance Floating Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
In the first argument of `print', namely `it'
In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

As far as I undrestand the actual *print* function that prints the result to the console is causing trouble, but I cannot find out what is wrong. It says the `type` is ambiguous, but the function can clearly only return a list of integers. Then again I checked the type, and it the (inferred) type of `f` is

```
f :: (Floating t, Integral t, RealFrac t) => t -> [t]
```

I can understand that `f`should be able to accept any real numerical value, but can anyone explain why the *return* type should be anything else than `Integral` or `int`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[k|k<-[1...floor(sqrt 10)],rem 10 k<1]
```

this works because the first `10` is not the same as the latter one - to see this, we need the type signature of your functions:

```
sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a
rem :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
```

so the first one means that it works for stuff that have a floating point representation - a.k.a. `Float`, `Double` ..., and the second one works for `Int`, `Integer` (bigint), `Word8` (unsigned 8bit integers)...

so for the `10` in `sqrt 10` the compiler says - ahh this is a floating point number, null problemo, and for the `10` in `rem 10 k`, ahh this is an integer like number, null problemo as well.

But when you bundle them up in a function - you are saying `n` has to be a floating point **and** an integral number, the compiler knows no such thing and - complains.

So what do we do to fix that (and a side note ranges in haskell are indicated by `..` not `...`!). So let us start by taking a concrete solution and generalize it.

```
f :: Int -> [Int]
f n = [k|k <- [1..n'],rem n k < 1]
    where n' = floor $ sqrt $ fromIntegral n
```

the neccessary part was converting the `Int` to a floating point number. But if you are putting that in a library all your users need to stick with using `Int` which is okay, but far from ideal - so how do we generalize (as promised)? We use GHCi to do that for us, using a lazy language we ourselves tend to be lazy as well.

We start by commenting out the type-signature

```
-- f :: Int -> [Int]
f n = [k|k <- [1..n'],rem n k < 1]
    where n' = floor $ sqrt $ fromIntegral n


$> ghci MyLib.hs
....
MyLib > :type f
f :: Integral a => a -> [a]
```

then we can take this and put it into the library and if someone worked with `Word8` or `Integer` that would work as well.

Another solution would be to use `rem (floor n) k < 1` and have

```
 f :: Floating a, Integral b => a -> [b]
```

as the type, but that would be kind of awkward.

Comment: Again thank you very much for the detailed explanation! At some point you will have to set up a tip jar because you seem to be answering all my haskell questions=)